# TypeError "can't convert nil into String" with omniauth-twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth, omniauth

I am using rails 3.2.1
omniauth-twitter (0.0.9)

But in twitter callback phase I receive this error :

```
TypeError "can't convert nil into String"

> omniauth-twitter (0.0.9) lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb:22:in `+'
omniauth-twitter (0.0.9) lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb:22:in `block in <class:Twitter>'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:106:in `instance_eval'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:106:in `block in compile_stack'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:105:in `each'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:105:in `inject'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:105:in `compile_stack'
(eval):7:in `info_stack'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:322:in `info'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:335:in `auth_hash'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:362:in `callback_phase'
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:58:in `callback_phase'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:226:in `callback_call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:182:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:49:in `call'
```

Adding twitter.rb code below :

```
> require 'omniauth-oauth'
require 'multi_json'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Twitter < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth
      option :name, 'twitter'
      option :client_options, {:authorize_path => '/oauth/authenticate',
                               :site => 'https://api.twitter.com'}

      uid { access_token.params[:user_id] }

      info do
        {
          :nickname => raw_info['screen_name'],
          :name => raw_info['name'],
          :location => raw_info['location'],
          :image => raw_info['profile_image_url'],
          :description => raw_info['description'],
          :urls => {
            'Website' => raw_info['url'],
            'Twitter' => 'http://twitter.com/' + raw_info['screen_name'], # 22 line no
          }
        }
      end

      extra do
        { :raw_info => raw_info }
      end

      def raw_info
        @raw_info ||= MultiJson.decode(access_token.get('/1/account/verify_credentials.json').body)
      rescue ::Errno::ETIMEDOUT
        raise ::Timeout::Error
      end

      alias :old_request_phase :request_phase

      def request_phase 
        screen_name = session['omniauth.params']['screen_name']
        if screen_name && !screen_name.empty?
          options[:authorize_params] ||= {}
          options[:authorize_params].merge!(:force_login => 'true', :screen_name => screen_name)
        end
        old_request_phase
      end


    end
  end
end
```

I have already updated omniauth-twitter gem and it remains at the same version mentioned above.

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Can you show us the code in `twitter.rb` ?

Comment: I have added twitter.rb code above in my post.

Comment: Thanks! Can you let us know `line 22`? There are a lot of potential issues with this file, so we need to know which line is causing the error!

Comment: I have given a comment on line no 22

Comment: Thanks - the first question is - where does `raw_info` variable come from?

Comment: I have added the complete file(twitter.rb) now and there is a method for raw_info there.

Comment: Oh yeah! Sorry about that

Comment: Okay, my immediate test would be to change `'http://twitter.com/' + raw_info['screen_name']` -> `'http://twitter.com/your_screen_name'` on line 22 -- I think the raw_info variable is not being populated

Comment: It worked after I hardcoded the string with my screen name.

Comment: Okay! So we know the problem... maybe we can look at why your screen name is not being loaded into the `raw-info` variable. Any chance you could post the `/verify_credentials.json` file?

Answer (score 3):

Its because `raw_info['screen_name']` value is nil and you can not concatenate it with the string.

Replace  `'http://twitter.com/' + raw_info['screen_name'], # 22 line no` with

```
"http://twitter.com/#{raw_info['screen_name']}",
```